# Rescaling a Frobenius integrable 1-form to make it closed

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Consider a smooth nowhere-zero $1$-form $\alpha$ on a smooth manifold $M$. Assume that

$\alpha \wedge d\alpha \equiv 0$.

Does it follow that there exists a smooth nowhere-zero function $f:M\to \Bbb R$ such that $f\alpha$ is closed?

(By the Frobenius theorem, for every point $x\in M$ there is a neighborhood $U\ni x$ and smooth $f_U:M\to \Bbb R$ such that $f_U \alpha|_U$ is closed, i.e. the *local* answer to my question is "yes". I am asking the global question.)

Comment: What happens if you try $\alpha = \cos^2x\,dy - \sin x\,dx$ on $\Bbb R^2$? (Oh, and presumably you meant to say that $\alpha$ is nowhere-zero?)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Ah, I see. We automatically have $\alpha \wedge d\alpha = 0$ for any $1$-form $\alpha$ on $\Bbb R^2$ for algebraic reasons. Also, your choice of $\alpha$ is nowhere-zero. If we integrate your $\alpha$ along any smooth closed loop $\Gamma$, the $\sin x dx$ term contributes nothing (since it is exact). On the other hand, if the loop $\Gamma$ is contained in the strip $0 < x < \pi/2$, an application of Stokes theorem to the integral of the first term shows that the resulting line integral $\int_\Gamma \alpha >0$. Hence $\int_\Gamma f\alpha \neq 0$ for any nowhere-zero $f$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: This shows that $f\alpha$ cannot be closed, because then we would have $f\alpha = dg$ for some smooth $g$ since the first de Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ vanishes. But then we have a contradiction: $0 = \int_\Gamma dg = \int_\Gamma f\alpha \neq 0$. 
Thank you very much for your help! If you'd like to leave this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. (Or I'd be happy to post my comments as an answer if you'd rather not spend the time.)

Comment: That's quite interesting. This is a Reeb-type foliation, and I was thinking about how $\alpha$ has an obvious integrating wherever $\cos x\ne 0$, but this fails along the lines $x=k\pi/2$ for $k$ odd. Indeed, I'm sort of stuck with a puzzle I should know how to solve: I don't see how to get a local integrating factor for $\alpha = y^2\,dx + dy$ at points where $y=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin  I’m curious: what is a “Reeb-type” foliation? Also, I fiddled with your puzzle for a bit but didn’t have any success with guess and check. But computing a local integrating factor via the method of characteristics should work, right? I computed the integrating factor $f(x,y) = (y(x_0 - x)+1)^2$ on a neighborhood of $(x_0,0)$. Odds are I made a mistake in the computation, and I didn’t check, but I’m content.

Comment: The correct integrating factor should have exponent $-2$; thanks. The usual Reeb foliation is a foliation of $S^3$ with one compact leaf (a $2$-torus) and non-compact "hyperboloid" leaves on either side. What I was looking at here is the foliation of $\Bbb R^2$ by the curves $y=\sec x + c$ and the lines $x=k\pi/2$ for $k$ an odd integer.